# Polar Coordinates ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

I have the following ODE:
$$\dot x=y+ax(x^2+y^2), \dot y=-x+ay(x^2+y^2)$$
and I want to prove that the system is equivalent with the following
$$\dot r=ar^3, \dot \theta=-1$$

I start by taking polar coordinates but when I make the change I get
$$ r \dot r=ax^4+2ax^2y^2+ay^4$$
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your last expression is exactly $a(x^2+y^2)^2=ar^4$ by binomial formula.

Answer (score 4):

If you differentiate the equations $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$, with respect to $t$ you obtain the following equations:
$$
\dot{r}=\frac{x\dot{x}+y\dot{y}}{r}
$$
$$
\dot{\theta}=\frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{r^2}.
$$

If you make the substitutions on this equation with your ODE, you directly get the statement.